# Sending Google Analytic event to specific tracking code

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

On my site, we have a custom dimension that we register on the Google Analytics config and then use it when we send our page view event:

```
gtag('config', 'UA-TrackingCode', {
    'custom_map': {
        'dimension1': 'CustomDim'
    },
    'send_page_view': false
});

gtag('event', 'page_view', {
    'CustomDim': value
});
```

However, running this code sends a page view for all Google Analytics instances loaded on the page prior to ours (which is causing a very high bounce rate for others).  I want this page view event to only register for my 'UA-TrackingCode' instance.

Is there a way to do this?  Something similar to:

```
gtag('event', 'UA-page_view', {
    'CustomDim': value,
    'TrackingCode': 'UA-TrackingCode'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use the "send_to" parameter:

```
gtag('event', 'page_view', {
    'CustomDim': value,
    'send_to': 'UA-TrackingCode'
});
```